Kaspersky AV and Zecurion DLP blocked each other?
I am running kaspersky EDR through Kaspersky center, however when I install it on machines that have Zecurion DLP installed, all ports of that server are blocked, even though the server is not off, it just blocks all ports, even it blocks servers on the same LAN IP. Has anyone encountered this case and can give me advice?
Thanks!!!
I need to install both kaspersky and zecurion but both of them not block each other
